# how to run translate command in open nmt

Tags: opennmt

1. I have a folder called sample1 which is residing in OpenNMT-py
   folder  i have completed first 2 steps that is

   1. Preparing the data  - have created vocabulary
   2. Train the data

   but as i am translating the data with this command

   You can check the following documentation
   https://github.com/OpenNMT/OpenNMT-py

   onmt_translate -model sample1/newmodel_step_1200.pt -src
   sample1/src-test.hi -output sample1/pred_1000.txt -verbose

   it shows following error

   (nmt1) C:\Users\anurag\OpenNMT-py>onmt_translate -model
   sample1/newmodel_step_1200.pt -src sample1/src-test.hi -output
   sample1/pred_1000.txt -verbose Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\anurag\anaconda3\envs\nmt1\lib\runpy.py", line 194,
   in _run_module_as_main
   return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,   File "C:\Users\anurag\anaconda3\envs\nmt1\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in
   *run_code
   exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\Users\anurag\anaconda3\envs\nmt1\Scripts\onmt_translate.exe_*main**.py",
   line 7, in    File
   "C:\Users\anurag\anaconda3\envs\nmt1\lib\site-packages\onmt\bin\translate.py",
   line 60, in main
   translate(opt)   File "C:\Users\anurag\anaconda3\envs\nmt1\lib\site-packages\onmt\bin\translate.py",
   line 41, in translate
   _, _ = translator._translate(   File "C:\Users\anurag\anaconda3\envs\nmt1\lib\site-packages\onmt\translate\translator.py",
   line 343, in _translate
   for batch in infer_iter:   File "C:\Users\anurag\anaconda3\envs\nmt1\lib\site-packages\onmt\inputters\inputter.py",
   line 28, in **iter**
   for tensor_batch in self.iterable:   File "C:\Users\anurag\anaconda3\envs\nmt1\lib\site-packages\onmt\inputters\dynamic_iterator.py",
   line 290, in **iter**
   for bucket in self._bucketing():   File "C:\Users\anurag\anaconda3\envs\nmt1\lib\site-packages\onmt\inputters\dynamic_iterator.py",
   line 231, in _bucketing
   for ex in self.mixer:   File "C:\Users\anurag\anaconda3\envs\nmt1\lib\site-packages\onmt\inputters\dynamic_iterator.py",
   line 45, in **iter**
   yield from iterable   File "C:\Users\anurag\anaconda3\envs\nmt1\lib\site-packages\onmt\inputters\text_corpus.py",
   line 209, in **iter**
   yield from indexed_corpus   File "C:\Users\anurag\anaconda3\envs\nmt1\lib\site-packages\onmt\inputters\text_corpus.py",
   line 186, in _add_index
   for i, item in enumerate(stream):   File "C:\Users\anurag\anaconda3\envs\nmt1\lib\site-packages\onmt\inputters\text_corpus.py",
   line 170, in _transform
   for example in stream:   File "C:\Users\anurag\anaconda3\envs\nmt1\lib\site-packages\onmt\inputters\text_corpus.py",
   line 153, in _tokenize
   for example in stream:   File "C:\Users\anurag\anaconda3\envs\nmt1\lib\site-packages\onmt\inputters\text_corpus.py",
   line 63, in load
   with exfile_open(self.src, mode='rb') as fs,\   File "C:\Users\anurag\anaconda3\envs\nmt1\lib\contextlib.py", line 113,
   in **enter**
   return next(self.gen)   File "C:\Users\anurag\anaconda3\envs\nmt1\lib\site-packages\onmt\inputters\text_corpus.py",
   line 32, in exfile_open
   _file = codecs.open(filename, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\anurag\anaconda3\envs\nmt1\lib\codecs.py", line 905, in
   open
   file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
   'sample1/src-test.hi'

Comment: onmt_translate -model sample1/newmodel_step_1200.pt -src sample1/src-test.hi -output sample1/pred_1000.txt -verbose

Comment: May be i am running this command from the wrong directory. please anyone help me please